# How to open my java application using process id

Tags: java, pid

Hi I have created a java swing application. If I run that application then it runs properly (a frame is created) and it is associated with a process id. when that application is running I want to see the that frame using process ID

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: A Few Quick Questions:
What OS are you intending to run it on as there is probably a way to do it natively.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
 String pid = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl -e 'print getppid()'").getInputStream()
              )).readLine();;
```

That will return the PID of the java process, but only if perl is installed